# What is the difference in "Indem wir uns über Dinge streiten" and "Indem über Dinge streiten"

Tags: meaning, translation

I have started learning German language. I am translating phrases from local language to German for practice.

Where I translate "**By arguing about things**" translation comes "**Indem wir uns über Dinge streiten**" but if I remove "**wir uns**" from it, the meaning still remains the same.

Anybody knows why we use **wir uns** here?

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Is English your local language? What translation machine creates your example? Can you link that? Is it Google? Well, google translate is only a hint, not a valid translation. What do you mean "still the same" - did you translate the leftover back (with same machine) and it produced same english phrase? (and who is "we" ... as it is not me)

Comment: Please have a look at [What topics can I ask about here?](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for some rules here on German SE.

Comment: Please check your writing. I guess it has to be "Indem wir un<b>s</b> über Dinge streiten and "wir uns" (2x), but of course I don't know your translation machine. Meanwhile I may suggest DeepL, which has to been shown a superior translation bot.

Comment: @HamzaRehmanSaleemi: Welcome and Marhaba or Salam. "sich über etwas streiten" is here the correct translation of "to argue about something", not just "streiten". Note that in other situations "streiten" without reflexivity may be correct. German's not a trivial language, keep it up :-)

Answer (score 5):

The difference is, that it referes to specific people (requires context who is involved). 
Without the "uns" it's more general. The "wir" is required, otherwise it's an incomplete sentence.

Answer (score 4):

*Indem über Dinge streiten* is not a German sentence (unless it is meant as very economical ellipse).

The right sentence contains *uns* not *un*.

So the difference is that

> Indem wir *uns* über Dinge streiten

*is* a sentence, the former is not. (We don't translate here, so I won't help with that part, unless you specify what is not clear).

Your confusion relies on the false assumption that a machine translator yields a correct sentence in the target language if and only if the source language is correct. In fact, it assumes your input is right (which as I argue, is not).

Answer (score 2):

*Sich streiten* is a reflexive word combination (you are actor and and the same time acted on), while *streiten* without *sich* has a different meaning and is less used today (see [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/streiten)). Thefore the sentencre becomes wrong omitting *wir uns*.

In this closely related [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/38925/1696) and its answers more background can be found.

Answer (score 2):

c.p. has already made the most important point: machine translation will not tell you whether the input contains errors.

Grammatically speaking, *indem* is a finite [subordinating conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(grammar)#Subordinating_conjunctions): it introduces a clause with a subject and a finite verb (marked in bold in the following examples).

> indem **man** über Dinge **streitet**
>   indem **wir** über Dinge **streiten**

Note that the verb *streiten* is frequently used [reflexively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_pronoun), i.e. a reflexive object is added.

> indem **man** **sich**  über Dinge **streitet**
>   indem **wir** **uns** über Dinge **streiten**

German also has non-finite  subordinating conjunctions where the subject must be omitted.

> Sie können nicht miteinander spielen, **ohne** (sich) **zu streiten**.
>   *They cannot play together without arguing.*