# "ich" and "mich" in same sentence

Tags: english-to-german, verb, reflexive

I am new to German and came across the phrase:

> "Darauf würde ich mich nicht verlassen"

I wouldn't count on that!

I don't understand why "mich" is used instead of just:

> "Darauf würde ich nicht verlassen"

Can you please explain?

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. What already learned rule etc. gave you the assumption that your proposal would be right? (and thx for having your own attempt :-)

Comment: What is so strange about having both in a sentence? In case you're coming from one of those languages where syntactic case applies to the whole sentence - *German isn't like that*. Our cases are governed by verbs or prepositions, and they extend only over one noun phrase.

Comment: Never attempt to understand one language using grammar from another (unless you know and understand the historical linguistic background). German isn't English and doesn't work the same way. In this case, the German verb is reflexive and the English verb isn't. Why? That's a misleading question, as it assumes that German should somehow conform to English.

Answer (score 4):

*Verlassen* is a reflexive verb, see [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/verlassen#2), so the person has an active and a passive role in the interaction. (Without reflexive pronoun, the meaning is a different one, corresponding to *abandon*.)

There are other reflexive verbs like *sich {die Hände} waschen* (see corresponding [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/38925/1696)), where the separation between the acting role and the receiving role is more obvious.

Answer (score 3):

English has only pseudo reflexive verbs, i.e. verbs, that *can* be used reflexive:

> Eric *introduces **himself*** to the class.
> Carol *washes **herself.***
> John accidentally *cut **himself*** with a knife.
> Laura *taught **herself*** how to beak bread.

But you can use all these verbs transitive too:

> Eric *introduces **his father*** to the class.
> Carol *washes **the car.***
> John accidentally *cut **the table*** with a knife.
> Laura *taught **Simon*** how to beak bread.

German has this kind of verbs too, but German has in addition verbs, that **always must** be used together with a reflexive pronoun. Omitting the reflexive pronoun would be wrong:

> Lisa *freut **sich.***
> <sup>Lisa is happy.</sup>
> Jürgen *bedankt **sich*** für die Hilfe.
> <sup>Jürgen thanks for the help.</sup>
> Barbara *ruht **sich** aus.*
> <sup>Barbara takes a rest.</sup>
> Lisa *fürchtet **sich** vor Spinnen.*
> <sup>Lisa is afraid of spiders.</sup>

etc.

And *»sich auf etwas verlassen«* is such a reflexive verb:

> correct: Ich *verlasse **mich*** auf dich.
> <sup>I'm counting on you.</sup>
> wrong: <del>Ich verlasse auf dich.</del>

But *»verlassen«* has a homonym with a very different meaning which is not reflexive, so don't mix them up:

> Ich verlasse dich.
> <sup>I leave you.</sup>

Comment: *Das freut mich* is not a reflexive use, is it? And *fürchten* could be transitive too.

Comment: @c.p.: That's a different meaning of "freuen". Note how in the meaning found in "Das freut mich.", which can be used non-reflexively, the subject is what generates the happiness, whereas in the meaning found in "Lisa freut sich.", which can only be used reflexively, whatever causes the happiness is not mentioned (or would be mentioned in a different way, as a prepositional object with "über"). The same pattern occurs in "fürchten".

Comment: @c.p.: If anything, "Barbara ruht sich aus." may be a bit of a borderline case, for at least in colloquial language, non-reflexive use of "ausruhen" appears to be slowly spreading, possibly (pure speculation!) also because there is a very similar non-reflexive verb "ruhen" with essentially the same meaning, and the two get mixed up by some speakers, *and* because the synonymous anglicism "relaxen" is non-reflexive, as well.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I don't understand. I am just referring to the English comparison. In your Lisa-example, notice that *John accidentally cut himself* (what causes it, one doesn't know) and *John accidentally cuts something* is similar. But Huber says this is pseudoreflexivity, while in German isn't. Why?

Comment: @c.p.: Yes, "John accidentally cuts himself." and "John accidentally cuts something." use "to cut" in the same way. In both cases, the one who executes the cut is the subject, and the one receiving the cut is the direct object, in the first example replaced by a reflexive pronoun - which is why this is only pseudo-reflexivity. But if I understood Hubert's explanations correctly, he doesn't claim that "John schneidet sich versehentlich." is *not* an example pseudo-reflexivity, just that, as opposed to German, English doesn't have any verbs that (within their context of prepositional ...

Comment: ... objects) can *only* be used with a reflexive pronoun.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Don't perjure yourself.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Not sure what you mean, would you care to rephrase?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I see. Thanks... Regarding David Vogt's comment, I guess that was an example (counter-example?) of a verb in the situation we now discuss (therefore meant inside quotation marks).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper c.p. is correct. I should have used italics. I'm sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Consider this

> I will rid **myself** of the burden.

It would not make sense without the reflexive *myself*.

Similarly, German has verbs like rid (*to rid oneself*) that are reflexive. They‘re listed in the dictionary as sich + verb, for example *sich verlassen*.

Another indicator of reflexitivity is *each other*.

> We kissed each other.

or the common (dare I say, infamous) mistake by German speakers:

> We‘ll see each other. (!*We‘ll see us* from German: Wir sehen uns.)

So by analogy,

> "Darauf würde ich mich nicht verlassen"

sounds weird without the mich in there like removing myself from *rid myself*.